# SharePoint search alert not working for external users

Tags: 2013, search, alert

I am not able to create alert for search result for external users. It provides me below error:

> The was a problem configuring your Search Alerts. It looks like you
>   don't have a valid user profile. To verify that your profile is
>   configured correctly, contact your administrator.

Then I tried same setting with windows authentication users but it ran without any error and I am getting search alert mails for any changes.

I have deleted my user profile service twice and recreated external users user profile using powershell. But still I am facing same error message. Is there any other solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The alerts system uses the site's user information list. After you create the external users using powershell you will also need to add them to the Site's user information list before being able to create an alert. The difference in behavior is likely Microsoft doing that step for you for the AD users because it knows what it is doing, and not doing it for external users because it is missing something or not able to be certain that you want the automatic part done.

[Simple version](http://oumaimasharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/03/add-users-to-sharepoint-group-using.html)

Comment: I am using trusted third party provider for external users. When I give this users permission by adding them to any group, SharePoint creates their user profile. this is the flow which I know. I an not getting point of user information list.